# How to acess COM port of remote system?

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-xp, embedded

I Want to access the COM port present in the remote system from system. Any help would be appreciable.

I am using windows XP in both remote as well as local system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) project, and especially the **com2tcp** application should help you.

> In conjunction with the Null-modem
>   emulator (com0com) the com2tcp enables
>   to use a COM port based applications
>   to communicate with the TCP/IP based
>   applications. It also allows
>   communication with a remote serial
>   port via the TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [SerProxy](http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html), which makes that com port looks like telnet:

> Serproxy is a multi-threaded proxy program for redirecting network socket connections to/from serial links, in cases where the remote end of the serial link doesn't have a TCP/IP stack (eg an embedded or microcontroller system). The proxy allows other hosts on the network to communicate with the system on the remote end of the serial link.

I also looked into com0com before, but I finally decide not to use it, as it requires a driver installation.  Where as serproxy just need to be run.  Another nice part is that if the com port is not being "used" remotely, I can still access it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Advanced Virtual COM Port](http://www.advancedvirtualcomport.com/) to share a COM port remotely.

On the local PC, it creates a virtual COM port that mirrors the activity of a real COM port on the remote PC. The remote PC can be on a local network or on the Internet. (If on the Internet, you just have to make sure your firewalls allow the particular TCP ports through.)

I tried several programs to share a COM port remotely, but this was the only one I found that also shared the serial hardware handshaking signals. So we picked this one, and it worked great. We used it about 3 years ago, to access a Japanese CDMA modem dev board, sitting in Japan, from Australia.